# Why do we feel "bumps" when dragging your fingers over an appliance with faulty grounding?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

Let us take a laptop which is plugged into a charger where the socket has improper grounding. (I do not know much more regarding this, might be current leakage.)

Now, when the charger is turned on and you drag your finger along the casing of the laptop, there is an unmistakable feeling your finger moving over a bumpy surface: the faster you move your finger, the more "bumps" you feel. You only feel this when there is some relative motion between your finger and the laptop.

What causes this sensation to arise?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the charger has “faulty grounding”?

Comment: @BobD, I know exactly the feeling that Alan is describing. I can't remember where I experienced it, but it was some piece of equipment with a matte, metal surface. When I rested my fingers on it, I felt nothing; but when I stroked my fingers across the surface, I felt the faintest "buzzy" feeling. When I subsequently unplugged the equipment and stroked it again, the "buzz" was gone. I've never given any thought to why the feeling depended on the motion of my fingers across the surface. I also (at the time) never was sure whether I was feeling leakage current, or mechanical vibration.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the reason I asked is the sensation may be low leakage associated with normal EMI filtering and not necessarily a fault condition.

Comment: @BobD I do not in fact know if it was due to faulty grounding. I've edited the question accordingly.